# Set Apache response header for a specific response status code

Tags: apache-2.2

When my PHP application returns a 301 status code, I would like to automatically add some headers to the response to prevent caching the redirect.

```
Header set "Expires" "Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT"
Header set "Cache-Control" "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
Header set "Pragma" "no-cache"
```

While I would normally add this at the application level, because of the way this application was built, it is not a fast fix.  As a stop-gap solution, I would like to configure Apache to add these headers, if possible.

How can I conditionally add these headers, based on the response status code?

Possibly related:  [Add a header depending on the proxied response code with apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/331544/add-a-header-depending-on-the-proxied-response-code-with-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using apache (the problem is the condition), but I have one idea how to solve it in application level but w/o changing the actual application.

Not sure, it you can do it, but it should work - anyway, I just tried to help :-)

I would create somewhere a PHP script defining function fixing the headers and registering it as [shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) of PHP:

```
<?php
  function fix_headers_on_shutdown() {
    $headers = headers_list();
    if(/* TODO: is redirect condition */) {
      header('Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT');
      header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
    }
  }
  register_shutdown_function('fix_headers_on_shutdown');
?>
```

And then make PHP to include this script on the start of each PHP script with [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) configuration option.

Comment: Not a bad idea!  I'll use this method if nobody knows of an Apache-only way.

Comment: As of apache httpd 2.4, it's possible. See the [linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/331544) from the description; an answer was provided in 2016. This answer here is still good for anyone in the same situation as OP though!