# Nginx Error 500 page no-cache

Tags: nginx, cache, 500-error

This doesn't make much sense, but it seems like when nginx serves up an error 500, it sends along a header that the client shouldn't check for new content the next time it connects.

I can get around it by refreshing, but some of my users have to fully clear their cache after they've hit it.

Is this the default functionality? And if so is there a way to prevent nginx from doing this?

If it makes a difference, it seems to happen when I'm restarting the Gunicorn process that nginx connects to to get the content.

Comment: `it sends along a header that the client shouldn't check for new content the next time it connects.` please put some evidence/indication of what you mean there - like the output of `curl -i http://example.com/should-be-a-500`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/690229/182909) from a different question and it solved my problem. It's worth noting though, it required updating to the latest version of nginx. It is mentioned in the comments but it is not immediately obvious.