# Disable cache for 404 ONLY, in apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, http-status-code-404

Is there any method to call RESPONSE_CODE in http.conf file --> check if it is ="404" --> Disable cache for 404 ONLY..

P.S. I am using Apache 2.2.

For apache 2.4 [I saw some help as below](https://serverfault.com/a/913671/256884):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>        
 Header always unset ETag "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"
 Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"    
 Header always set Pragma "no-cache" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"    
 Header always set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} == 404"    
</IfModule>
```

Any help in apache 2.2 ?

Comment: I think the above is valid syntax in apache http 2.2 as well, what happens when you tried that?

Comment: @ HBrujin, yes I tried. It resulted me syntax error. "envclause should be in the form env=envar"

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you should at least be able add headers when you set up custom error pages with an [`ErrorDocument`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) Directive and then add [`Header`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) directives on the `Location` of the custom error pages.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-pages/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error-pages/500.html

<Location /error-pages/>
     Header always unset ETag
     Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header always set Pragma "no-cache" 
</Location
```